# If two key domains are using the same auth key but different subject key ID does this mean it is operated by the same user/organisation?

Tags: encryption

How do you verify if two domains are using the same SSL certificate? Two identified two domains are using the same Authority Key ID, but different subject key ID and public key value. Does this mean they are operated by the same user/organisation?

Answer (score 1):

> Two identified two domains are using the same Authority Key ID... Does this mean they are operated by the same user/organisation?

No, it just means that these certificates where issued by the same CA. This might be a company specific CA or a public CA. For examples all the zillions of certificates for public sites which were recently issued by Let's Encrypt have the same AKI, even though most of these are operated by different organisations.